# Magento 1.9.1 reindex all: PHP Fatal error

Tags: magento, upgrade, reindex

During magento upgrade, when I tried to reindex all:

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindexall
```

I got following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getProcessesCollection()
>   on a non-object in /shell/indexer.php on line 58

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Not really, I had to restart an installation altogether.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can be of help to anyone finding this ticket a year after.

I had the same situation at hand, but after upgrading it is advised to clear the cache before running any function at all.

Before running `php shell/indexer.php --reindexall` i got the same result;

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getProcessesCollection()
>   on boolean etc.

But after running `rm -rf downloader/.cache/ var/cache/`

The `php shell/indexer.php --reindexall` command started working again.

Comment: `rm -rf var/cache/*` helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this class file is missing: Mage_Index_Model_Indexer (in app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer.php).

On line 58 of shell/indexer.php:

```
$collection = $this->_getIndexer()->getProcessesCollection();
```

_getIndexer() returns the model as declared in the Index module configuration:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Index>
            <version>1.6.0.0</version>
        </Mage_Index>
    </modules>
    <global>
        ...        
        <index>
            <index_model>index/indexer</index_model>
        </index>
        ...
```

Comment: I have the same problem. The `global/index/index_model` parameter is passed to `$this->_config->getNode()` in `Mage_Core_Model_Factory`, but that call returns false. The config.xml exists and contains the text above. Very confusing! The code works on my local dev box, but not on a live server.